# Passar dois conjuntos de valores do AJAX para controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Preciso passar os valores de uma view model, e de uma tabela, a da tabela está passando normalmente, quando passada sozinha, a do viewmodel não.
Segue como estou fazendo:

```
var model1 = objectifyForm(model);
    console.log(model1);
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Novo1", "PedidoFornecedor")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: { valores: JSON.stringify(valores), model: model1 }
    });
```

Essa é a função que pega os input do form:

```
 function objectifyForm(formArray) {//serialize data function

    var returnArray = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
        returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Porém no controller, de toda a forma que eu tento, um vem vazio, ou não vem com os dados corretos, como posso proceder?

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Novo1([FromBody]List<PedidosProdutosF> valores, NovoViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
```

Comment: mariana você vai ter que unir os dois objetos em um só e enviar um unico objeto

Comment: Como assim, unir os objetos ?

Comment: Vou escrever uma resposta

Comment: da uma olhada, se não funcionar me da detalhes que eu corrijo, principalmente na parte de criar o objeto novo no c#

Comment: pode colocar a classe NovoViewModel  e quais valores está passando no model1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só você unificar os dois objetos dentro de um só, Ajax só passa apenas um objeto para o Controller...

```
var model1 = objectifyForm(model);
var _objetoUnificado = {Model:model1 , Valores:valores}; //passar esse objeto no AJAX
console.log(model1);
debugger;
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Novo1", "PedidoFornecedor")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: { objetoUnificado:_objetoUnificado }
}); 


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Novo1([FromBody]ObjetoUnificado objetoUnificado)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
}
```

Ai no seu C#, você cria um objeto chamado `ObjetoUnificado` com o `NovoViewModel` e `List<PedidosProdutosF>`

Comment: Eu crio a classe, com os dados, desta forma: `public class ObjetoUnificado {
            NovoViewModel model = new NovoViewModel();
            List<PedidosProdutosF> valores = new List<PedidosProdutosF>();
        }`

Comment: Sim, porém coloca os nomes iguais ao que está no javascript, mas ai fica de acordo com o que  você achar melhor, no meu exemplo ficou "Model" e "Valores" maiúsculo

Comment: Lembre-se , o javascript tem que ser um espelho do objeto C#, ele é case sensitive também ;)

Comment: Eu tentei, alterando para a primeira letra pra maiúsculo, porém mesmo assim, vem em null. `public class ObjetoUnificado {
            NovoViewModel Model = new NovoViewModel();
            List<PedidosProdutosF> Valores = new List<PedidosProdutosF>();
        }`

Comment: Como você está passando no ajax? igual ao que eu fiz?

Comment: Igualzinho, da mesma forma, Tentei até passando os parametros como JSON.stringify, e mesmo assim, ele sempre vai null.

Comment: Infelizmente, de toda forma que eu tento, retorna sempre null.

Comment: @marianac_costa vi na sua outra pergunta, que o `objetoUnificado` está minusculo no JS e maiúsculo no c#

Comment: Ele reconhece a classe, mas não passa os valores, no debugger eu vejo os valores corretamente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82370/discussion-between-leonardo-bonetti-and-marianac-costa).